# Convert escaped characters PHP

Tags: php, escaping

I know this is a simple question, but having a hard time finding a simple solution.

I have a form on my PHP site that takes in the user message, then sends an email to my client with the message. I want the message sent to my client to be easily readable, without escaped characters \r , \n , \" , etc.

For example, the message is currently coming into the email as:

```
test\'s\r\nnew line \r\n\"quote\"
```

What I want it to come in as:

```
test's
new line 
"quote"
```

**Current code is:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){
    //Process form
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $name = mysql_prep($name);
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $email = mysql_prep($email);
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $message = mysql_prep($message);

    $emailto = "client_email1@gmail.com,client_email2@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Message from '$name'";
    // the message
    $message = "<html><body>
                <h3>Title</h3>
                From: $name<br>
                Email: $email<br><br>
                Message:<br>
                $message<br><br>

                </body></html>";
    //headers make the mail() work
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    mail($emailto, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Found out the error, `$message = mysql_prep($message);` was just moved after the `mail()` function, but now the user entered line break does not appear in the message. Any idea how I get the line break to show in the email I send to my client?

Comment: what does `mysql_prep()` do?

Comment: *"Found out the error, $message = mysql_prep($message); was just moved after the mail() function"* - That should have been made part of the original post and what you wrote should be added in there too and as an additional edit.

Comment: Seems like a possible SQL injection to me and seems to be database related. There are a few ways to not have those backslashes be part of the message.

Comment: You came here asking for help and we are trying to help, but you probably left and trying to figure it out for yourself, which we don't know if that's what's happening here. I asked for an update to the question (10 mins. prior to this comment), but I for one did not see one, nor a response to some of my comments. I will have to move on now, since I appear to be of no worth; good luck, really.

Comment: How about: `$message = stripslashes (strtr ($message, array ('\b' => "\b", '\n' => "\n", '\r' => "\r", '\t' => "\t")));` ?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is stripslashes() and nl2br().
nl2br will make newlines html br tags.
Stripslashes does what the name indicates, it removes slashes that is escape slashes.

```
echo stripslashes(nl2br($str));
```

Example: https://3v4l.org/RPYWt

Comment: Not what I am looking for, that just strips the slash out of `\r\n`, but leaves the `rn`

Comment: No it doesn't! Look at the code and the link

Comment: @Andreas Right; I can't see what you posted as an answer be failing here. I posted a few comments under their question; they also posted a comment up there. The question is starting to look unclear and from the "get go".

Comment: @AlexB str_replace won't work, not as I see it. But if you find it a better answer then post it. What do you think does not work with this answer?

Answer (score -1):

Couple issues, first was my `$message = mysql_prep($message);` function was creating the escaped characters, so I just put that function after the `mail()` function. `mysql_prep()` was used to prevent mysql injection.

Second, I needed the `$message = nl2br($message)` function to maintain the user entered new lines from the form so the client can see the message as it was typed. I put the `nl2br()` function just after the `$message = $_POST['message'];` line.